# React Styled-Components 3 Button sizes

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

What is the best way have 3 style types based on props?

Like Bootstrap, aiming to have a default, small, and medium size.

Here I have default and small, but how do I account for a large size too?

```
 const Button = styled.button`
   background: teal;
   border-radius: 8px;
   color: white;
   height: ${props => props.small ? 40 : 60}px;
   width: ${props => props.small ? 60 : 120}px;
`;

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button small>Click Me</Button>
        <Button>Click Me</Button>
        <Button large>Click Me</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/chancesmith/pen/aYbWvv?editors=0010)

Comment: So you're looking for dynamic styles?

Comment: or like.. a switch instead of a ternary?

Comment: A switch sounds more like it. I'm trying to find a fitting way to handle a theme + variant styles like Bootstrap uses classes to have different sized buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an abbreviated example of an option that I use.

```
/* import separate css file from styles.js */
import * as Styles from './styles';

/* concat styles based on props */
const ButtonBase = styled.button`
  ${Styles.buttonbase};
  ${props => Styles[props.size]};
  ${props => Styles[props.variant]};
`;

const Button = ({ size, variant, ...rest }) => (
  <ButtonBase
    size={size}
    variant={variant}
    {...rest}
    ...
```

And in the styles file (with the css removed for brevity)

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';

/* styles common to all buttons */
export const buttonbase = css`...`;

/* theme variants */
export const primary = css`...`;
export const secondary = css`...`;
export const tertiary = css`...`;

/* size variants */
export const small = css`...`;
export const medium = css`...`;
export const large = css`...`;
```

Comment: Any idea on how would this translate when using Typescript? For example, `Property 'size' does not exist on type HTMLButtonElement `

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this as a solution too:

```
const ButtonBase = styled.button`
    padding: ${props => {
        if (props.xl) return props.theme.buttonSize.xl;
        if (props.lg) return props.theme.buttonSize.lg;
        if (props.md) return props.theme.buttonSize.md;
        if (props.sm) return props.theme.buttonSize.sm;
        return props.theme.buttonSize.nm;
    }};
`
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/735ppo790x

Answer (score 1):

Harsha Venkatram, here is the typescript version:

```
import * as Styles from './styles';

interface Props {
  size: number; //for example, or string or whatever type is it
  variant: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary' //etc...
}

const ButtonBase = styled.button<Props>`
  ${Styles.buttonbase};
  ${props => Styles[props.size]};
  ${props => Styles[props.variant]};
`;
```